# Curse of dimensionality: is there a benchmark test set?

Tags: machine-learning, high-dimensional

I am working on the curse of dimensionality (theoretical models) and would like to test an algorithm on it.  What I haven't found is a standard dataset that could be used to compare different approaches.

Is there such a thing?  Or... related: what is the most well-known failure due to the curse of dimensionality?

Answer (score 1):

Zimek, Schubert and Kriegel have a good [paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sam.11161/abstract) on outlier detection in High-Dimensional data. They use a simple method of generating sample data to illustrate the problem:

> [..] we plot some characteristics of the distribution of vector length
>   values for vectors uniformly distributed in the unit cube over
>   increasing dimensionality d. The observed length of each vector is
>   normalized by 1/√d . Plotted are mean and standard deviation of the
>   observed lengths as well as the actually observed mini- mal (maximal)
>   length in each dimensionality. While the observed distances now have a
>   comparable average value, there is still a loss in relative contrast.
>   On this dataset of a sample of 105 instances, the curse (more
>   explicitly, the effect of distance concentration) is now clearly
>   visible: the standard deviation disappears already at 10 dimensions,
>   and the observed actual minimum and maximum shrink rapidly with
>   increasing dimensionality.

To study the actual problem, which for them is outlier detection, they generate two series. The first is uniformly distributed on the interval [0,1] and the second series, which introduces the outliers they wish to study, is a normal distribution.

Maybe one of these approaches can help you.